# Access Database from Different Server

Tags: php, database

I want to access my database that is on another server.
My database lies on server A.
User accessing webpage is lies on server B.
I have made one config.php file is act as third party or intermediate between server A and server B that lies on server A. The config.php access database according to requirement and send data to user on server B.
I am passing a bulk of data through URL parameter using config.php.

But, It shows me Error like

"Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /DataScripts/home.php on this server."

Anyone suggest me what is this error and what can I do?

Comment: Are the servers on the same network? If so, just connect to the database over the network rather than through some convoluted API.  Also, that forbidden error sounds like Apache, not PHP.

Comment: try to remotely access the db on server A from server B for this you have to configure the DB to allow remote access

Comment: Does `chmod 777 home.php` help? This isn't the best way to solve the problem, just a debugging step... this is also only if you're on a linux server.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is MySQL, and that you control both servers, on server B, ssh in and edit `my.cnf`. Scroll down to the `[mysqld] section and add this line:

```
bind-address=SERVER-B-IP-ADDRESS
```

Save and exit. Launch mysql.

Type the following pseudo-SQL:

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO adminuser@'SERVER-A-IP' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD';
```

Depending on your firewall setup you may have to whitelist server A's IP address as well as add it to the remote access list.

Comment: When I do not passing any parameter then Its works. But When I am passing bulk of data in parameter then it shows error as I mentioned in question.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look at the permissions for `/DataScripts/home.php` and make sure it is accessible.

Why don't you just connect directly to your DB on ServerA from the scripts running on ServerB?

Comment: When I do not passing any parameter then Its works. But When I am passing bulk of data in parameter then it shows error as I mentioned in question.

Comment: How are you passing data? through `GET` or `POST`? If it is through `GET` I would look at the resulting query string and make sure it's properly formed. Your HTTP server might be interpreting the query string as part of the filename you're trying to access (thereby giving you the forbidden error).